# Regex: Specify "space or start of string" and "space or end of string"

Tags: regex, preg-match

Imagine you are trying to pattern match "stackoverflow".

You want the following:

```
 this is stackoverflow and it rocks [MATCH]

 stackoverflow is the best [MATCH]

 i love stackoverflow [MATCH]

 typostackoverflow rules [NO MATCH]

 i love stackoverflowtypo [NO MATCH]
```

I know how to parse out stackoverflow if it has spaces on both sites using:

```
/\s(stackoverflow)\s/
```

Same with if its at the start or end of a string:

```
/^(stackoverflow)\s/

/\s(stackoverflow)$/
```

But how do you specify "space or end of string" and "space or start of string" using a regular expression?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can use any of the following:

```
\b      #A word break and will work for both spaces and end of lines.
(^|\s)  #the | means or. () is a capturing group. 


/\b(stackoverflow)\b/
```

Also, if you don't want to include the space in your match, you can use lookbehind/aheads.

```
(?<=\s|^)         #to look behind the match
(stackoverflow)   #the string you want. () optional
(?=\s|$)          #to look ahead.
```

Comment: `\b` is a zero-width assertion; it never consumes any characters.  There's no need to wrap it in a lookaround.

Comment: good point. I was thinking about his original `\s`. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Note that in most regexp implementations, `\b` is **standard ASCII only**, that is to say, no unicode support. If you need to match unicode words you have no choice but to use this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6713327/1329367

Comment: The easier way to exclude the group selection from the match is `(?:^|\s)`

Comment: for python, replace `(?<=\s|^)` with `(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))`.  Otherwise, you get `error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: Thanks for the look behind and look ahead solution.  This makes results comparable to \b

Comment: The `\b` would consider other characters -- such as "`.`" as word-breakers, whereas the asker specifically said "space". @gordy's solution seems better.

Comment: Beware: lookbehind is not implemented [in most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) as of 2019.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713427/11069485) for a Python-friendly regex that's a bit neater than the one suggested by @user2426679

Answer (score 101):

`(^|\s)` would match space or start of string and `($|\s)` for space or end of string. Together it's:

```
(^|\s)stackoverflow($|\s)
```

Comment: If you use this pattern to replace, remember to keep the spaces in the replaced result by replacing with the pattern `$1string$2`.

Comment: This is the only one that works for me too. Word boundaries never seem to do what I want. For one, they match some characters besides whitespace (like dashes). This solved it for me because I'd been trying to put `$` and `^` into a character class, but this shows they can just be put into a regular pattern group.

Comment: This works quite nicely but if you are not interested in capturing the spaces use this: `(?:^|\s)stackoverflow(?:$|\s)`

Answer (score 29):

Here's what I would use:

```
 (?<!\S)stackoverflow(?!\S)
```

In other words, match "stackoverflow" if it's not *preceded* by a non-whitespace character and not *followed* by a non-whitespace character.

This is neater (IMO) than the "space-or-anchor" approach, and it doesn't assume the string starts and ends with word characters like the `\b` approach does.

Comment: good explanation on why to use this. i would have picked this however the string being tested is ALWAYS a single line.

Comment: @LawrenceDol, did you mean `(?<=\S)...(?=\S)`?   Note that the uppercase `\S` matches any character that's NOT whitespace.  So the negative lookarounds will match if there IS a whitespace character there, or if there's no character at all.

Answer (score 12):

`\b` matches at word boundaries (without actually matching any characters), so the following should do what you want:

```
\bstackoverflow\b
```

Comment: For Python it helps to specify it a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-19), e.g. `mystr = r'\bstack overflow\b'`