# How to make regex match space OR end of string?

Tags: php, regex

I need to make a regex to match some liquid volumes like:

```
water in 17oz container
water in container 17oz
```

How would you make a regex to match these?
I could do just `/[0-9]{1,}oz/` but that will also match 90ozonelayers, not that it will happen but I want it to be foolproof.

And `/[0-9]{1,}oz /` will not do the trick to match it if its in the end of the string.

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace (e.g. spaces, tabs and new lines)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713310/how-to-specify-space-or-end-of-string-and-space-or-start-of-string

Comment: What about `/[0-9]{1,}oz[\s$]/`?

Comment: @EugenRieck, that matches a literal "$" or a space.

Comment: @tenub My bad, must be `/[0-9]{1,}oz(\s|$)/` or similar

Comment: @KristianRafteseth Consider accepting one of the two Answers or ask for further Detail. This will prevent this Question from getting any more Attention and also show at least some appreciation for the people who took the time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\b` to match the word boundary:

```
/\b[0-9]+oz\b/
```

Comment: This is also an incorrect solution, as the word boundary matches any non-word character, ie. `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. This means "17oz" from "17ozŵald" would match.

Comment: Great fine-grained observation, @tenub. Darn Unicode! :}

Comment: @KristianRafteseth: Consider marking this answer accepted so that others know it was exactly what you were looking for...without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]{1,}oz(\s|\b)`

This matches on your two strings, but doesn't match on something like `12ozsdsds`.

**EDIT:**

Noticing that all solutions are slightly flawed, it seems taking a combination of all things, the best might be something like (stolen bits from **tenub**):

`/(?<=\s|^)[0-9]{1,}oz(?=\s|$)/` (use `/g` to match all occurrences).

`17oz` - match

`abc 17oz def` - match

`17ozz` - no match

`abc17oz` - no match

Comment: This would match "17oz" in "17ozå".

Comment: That's true, although so would xdazz's, and yours matches `asdasd17oz` (As does mine, so correcting to amalgamate the best of all worlds).

Comment: Do note that this would not work for JavaScript due to the lookbehind (although the OP specified PHP so it shouldn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just use:

```
/[0-9]{1,}oz(?= |$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches 34oz, 34 oz and 6oz at the end of the string, but not the 56ozone layer.

```
([0-9]{0,})(\s{0,})(oz{1})(\s{0,}|$)
```