# Preg_match_all with Word Boundary and Non-alphanumeric Characters

Tags: php, preg-match-all

How can I detect the dot at the beginning of `".net"` with a `preg_match_all` pattern so I can also `echo ".net"` from the `$skills` list as well as the others keywords?

```
$skill = array(".net","software framework","microsoft");
$text = ".NET Framework is a software framework developed by Microsoft";

foreach ($skill as $skills) {
    preg_match_all("~\b$skills\b~i", $text, $matchWords);
    foreach ($matchWords[0] as $matchWord) {
        echo "<b>MatchWord:</b> " . $matchWord.  "<br>";
    }    
}
```

> Output (I'm Missing .NET): **MatchWord:** software framework **MatchWord:** Microsoft

Comment: The `.` isn't a literal `.` as your currently have it written.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713310/how-to-specify-space-or-end-of-string-and-space-or-start-of-string will answer it. You also should use `preg_quote` though. https://3v4l.org/J8mBO

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `\b` which you can't do without it? Or what are you trying to do with your code at all and what are your challenges you get when you try to solve your problem/issue/task?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. ".net" in regular expressions means "a four letter word starting with any character then the characters n, e, t".  That's because `.` is a special match-all operator.
2. The problem is that using `\b` means "start next match after a word boundary", so in essence the `\b` is causing the the dot to be skipped.

One possible solution is to change `.net` to `net` in your `$skills` array, then allow matching of any word that starts with a dot by adding `\.?`: `"~\b\.?$skills\b~i"`.  In this version the `\b` is still there, so `net` won't match `ASP.NET`.

Notice that the dot is escaped (`\.`) due to it being a special "match all" operator in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
$skill = array(".net","software framework","microsoft");
$text = ".NET Framework is a software framework developed by Microsoft";

foreach ($skill as $skills) {
preg_match_all("~(?<!\S)$skills(?!\S)~i", $text, $matchWords);
foreach ($matchWords[0] as $matchWord) {

     echo "<b>MatchWord:</b> " . $matchWord.  "<br>";
 }    
}
```

Output with.Net:
**MatchWord:** .NET
**MatchWord:** software framework
**MatchWord:** Microsoft

Follow the link from user3783243 for more information.