# How to check if a string ONLY contains specific strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test if a string ONLY contains specific substrings (as whole words) / spaces

I've written some code and it works, but I am concerned that I don't understand the regex (I've copied from elsewhere)

Is there a way of doing this without complex regex?

```js
const str1 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a'; // valid
const str2 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ aa'; // invalid aa
const str3 = 'a♭ apple ad  a a a apple   a♭ a'; // invalid ad
const str4 = ' a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a'; // valid
const str5 = ' a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a '; // valid
const str6 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a '; // valid
const str7 = '      '; // invalid
const str8 = ''; // invalid

const allowedSubstrings = [
  'a', 'a♭', 'apple'
]

const isStringValid = str => {
  if (str.trim() === '') return false
  allowedSubstrings.forEach(sub => {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713427/1205871
    // regex for whole words only
    const strRegex = `(?<!\\S)${sub}(?!\\S)`
    const regex = new RegExp(strRegex, 'g')
    str = str.replace(regex, '')
  })
  str = str.replaceAll(' ', '')
  // console.log(str)
  return str === ''
}

console.log('str1', isStringValid(str1))
console.log('str2', isStringValid(str2))
console.log('str3', isStringValid(str3))
console.log('str4', isStringValid(str4))
console.log('str5', isStringValid(str5))
console.log('str6', isStringValid(str6))
console.log('str7', isStringValid(str7))
console.log('str8', isStringValid(str8))
```

Comment: @danday74, this seems to work but im not sure im not able to extract capture group, maybe someone can build on this! `((?![apple|a|a♭| ]).)*` done on [`regexr.com`](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: @mandy8055 if there is a keyword matched, then it means its an invalid value right?

Comment: @mandy8055 Yes, if you check on regexr.com that regex identifies the `d` keyword, which should ideally be outputed in the capture group!

Comment: @mandy8055 I think its wrong what I made, appologies for confusion!

Comment: Do you also want to match an empty string? (as your code currently does)

Comment: @Thefourthbird good point! I'm not sure of the answer myself yet but I'll check how my code works and fix if needed :) thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach which I can think of (which avoids complex `regex`) would be to:

1. split the string based on one or more whitespace characters (space, tabs or others)
2. check if every word in the `words` array (created by above split) is included in the `allowedSubstrings` array.

```js
const str1 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a'; // valid
const str2 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ aa'; // invalid aa
const str3 = 'a♭ apple ad  a a a apple   a♭ a'; // invalid ad
const str4 = ' a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a'; // valid
const str5 = ' a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a '; // valid
const str6 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a '; // valid
const str7 = '      '; // invalid
const str8 = ''; // invalid

const allowedSubstrings = [
  'a', 'a♭', 'apple'
];

const isStringValid = (str) => {
  const words = str.trim().split(/\s+/);
  // If the requirement would be to make them valid, we can use trim().
  // const words = str.trim().split(/\s+/);
  return words.every(word => allowedSubstrings.includes(word));
};

// const isStringValid = (str) => str.split(/\s+/).every(word => allowedSubstrings.includes(word));

console.log('str1', isStringValid(str1));
console.log('str2', isStringValid(str2));
console.log('str3', isStringValid(str3));
console.log('str4', isStringValid(str4));
console.log('str5', isStringValid(str5));
console.log('str6', isStringValid(str6));
console.log('str7', isStringValid(str7));
console.log('str8', isStringValid(str8));
```

Comment: much more intelligent than my approach - will accept if no1 comes up with a better answer shortly

Comment: accepted this answer thx - added a trim() to your code after you pointed out failing test cases - many thx :)

Answer (score 3):

A single regular expression pattern that checks whether the string contains only the specified substrings as whole words or spaces. It uses the `join('|')` method to create an alternation pattern (`|`) for the allowed substrings and then tests the string against this pattern using `test()`.

```js
const str1 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a'; // valid
const str2 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ aa'; // invalid aa
const str3 = 'a♭ apple ad  a a a apple   a♭ a'; // invalid ad

const allowedSubstrings = [
  'a',
  'a♭',
  'apple'
];

const isStringValid = str => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`^((${allowedSubstrings.join('|')})(\\s+|$))+$`);
  return regex.test(str);
};

console.log('str1', isStringValid(str1));
console.log('str2', isStringValid(str2));
console.log('str3', isStringValid(str3));
```

Comment: This returns `false` for `' a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a '` and `' a♭ apple ad  a a a apple   a♭ a'` which as per OP should be `true`. You can fix this with the alternation with start of string too(`^`) though.

Answer (score 1):

strong text

```js
const str1 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ a'; // valid
const str2 = 'a♭ apple a a a a a apple   a♭ aa'; // invalid aa
const str3 = 'a♭ apple ad  a a a apple   a♭ a'; // invalid ad

const allowedSubstrings = [
  'a',
  'a♭',
  'apple'
];

const isStringValid = str => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`^((${allowedSubstrings.join('|')})(\\s+|$))+$`);
  return regex.test(str);
};

console.log('str1', isStringValid(str1));
console.log('str2', isStringValid(str2));
console.log('str3', isStringValid(str3));
```

Comment: Other than the weird `iframe` at the top of your post, this looks like **exactly** the same code as in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77744611/10871073).